# ¿cómo puedo recorrer un arreglo de formato JSON en Android con ListView?

Tags: android, mysql, json, sqlite

quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con un Arreglo, el caso es que tengo un web service en PHP en el cual imprimo el siguiente arreglo.

**Arreglo JSON PHP**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora logré imprimirlo en un ListView en android pero el caso es que solo me imprime el primer registro del JSON como se puede ver en la siguiente imagén

[image: Captura de pantalla]

y este es mi código de la clase.

```
public class Concesionarios extends AppCompatActivity {

public ListView lstEmp;
public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myItemEmp;
public AdapterEmpresas myAdapterEmp;

//DAO EMPRESAS;
public DaoEmpresas myDaoEmp;

//conexion base de datos
private String ip = "192.168.42.49";
private final String URL_SERVICE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/servidor.php#";
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/";
private String METHOD_NAME = "";
private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;


private SoapObject request;
private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelo;
private HttpTransportSE transport;


private PropertyInfo empresa = null;

ProgressDialog dialogAsynk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_concesionarios);

    lstEmp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstConcesionarios);
    myItemEmp = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();

    myAdapterEmp = new AdapterEmpresas(this, myItemEmp);
    lstEmp.setAdapter(myAdapterEmp);
    registerForContextMenu(lstEmp);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,0,0, "Actualizar");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 0:
            new EmpresaEnSegundoPlano().execute("");
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

public void reload(){
    myDaoEmp = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());
    myItemEmp = myDaoEmp.getAllEmpresas();
    myAdapterEmp = new AdapterEmpresas(this, myItemEmp);
    lstEmp.setAdapter(myAdapterEmp);
}

public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> LanzarEmpresa(String params){
    METHOD_NAME = "getEmpresa";
    SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

    ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myArrayWs = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();

    try {
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        empresa = new PropertyInfo();
        empresa.setName("empresa");
        empresa.setValue(params);
        empresa.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(empresa);


        envelo = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelo.dotNet = false;
        envelo.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_SERVICE);
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelo);

        String resultado = (String) envelo.getResponse();

        Type tipo = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>() {}.getType();

        Gson convertidoJson = new Gson();

        myArrayWs = convertidoJson.fromJson(resultado, tipo);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myArrayWs;
}

//**********************Tarea asyncrona***********************//
class EmpresaEnSegundoPlano extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> doInBackground(String... params) {
        return LanzarEmpresa(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialogAsynk = ProgressDialog.show(Concesionarios.this,"","espera",true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresases) {
        super.onPostExecute(itemEmpresases);
        dialogAsynk.dismiss();



        if (itemEmpresases.size() >= 1){
            DaoEmpresas myDao = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());
            ItemEmpresas myEmpresa = new ItemEmpresas();

            myEmpresa.setNombre(itemEmpresases.get(0).getNombre());

            if (myDao.insertEmpresa(myEmpresa) == true){

                Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                reload();
            }
        }else {
            Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
}
}
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar para poder imprimir todos los registros del JSON, y de igual forma quisiera preguntar si es necesario tener que guardar esos registros en una base de datos de SQLite.

Comment: utiliza AsyncResponse es mas facil

Comment: Necesito investigar sobre eso porque no lo habia escuchado

Comment: muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Tengo una duda. Que devuelve ` return myArrayWs;` desde el objeto GSON? puedes verificar que realmente parse el json  como tu quieres y que el objeto tiene datos? la [documentación](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#primitives-examples) dice que se usa class para la deserializacion :P pero nunca he usado Gson :P

Comment: con el ` return myArrayWs;` estoy indicando que me regrese el JSON que tengo en el WS ya convertido a Gson para que posteriormente pueda pasarlo al ListView

Comment: Respondi una pregunta similar de base de datos Android + PHP + MySQL, mira aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55581/32600

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)