# actualizar datos en una base de datos remota android studio

Tags: mysql, android-studio, json

Estoy tratando de insertar datos en una base de datos mysql remota.. 
Me encuentro atorado.. he buscado ejemplos pero nada parecido

Este es mi codigo java

```
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.RadioGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Modificar extends AppCompatActivity {
String status;
ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
Context context = null;
TextView tvnombre,
        tvfolio,
        tvasunto,
        tvfecha,
        tvdireccion,
        tvtelefono,
        tvlugar,
        tvestado;

EditText txobservaciones;
Button actualizar, borrar, turnar;

RadioButton activo,pendiente,concluido,noprocede;
RadioGroup grupo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modificar);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nombre = intent.getStringExtra("nombre");
    String folio = intent.getStringExtra("folio");
    String asunto = intent.getStringExtra("asunto");
    String fecha = intent.getStringExtra("fecha");
    String direccion = intent.getStringExtra("direccion");
    String telefono = intent.getStringExtra("telefono");
    String lugar = intent.getStringExtra("lugar");
    String estado = intent.getStringExtra("estado");
    String observaciones = intent.getStringExtra("observaciones");

    tvnombre = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvnombre);
    tvasunto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvasunto);
    tvfolio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfolio);
    tvfecha = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfecha);
    tvdireccion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdireccion);
    tvestado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvestado);
    tvtelefono = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtelefono);
    tvlugar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvlugar);
    txobservaciones = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txobservaciones);
    actualizar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmodificar);
    borrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnborrar);
    turnar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnturnar);
    activo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioActivo);
    pendiente = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioPendiente);
    concluido = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioConcluido);
    noprocede = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioNoprocede);
    grupo = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    tvnombre.setText(nombre);
    tvasunto.setText(asunto);
    tvfolio.setText("Folio: "+folio);
    tvfecha.setText(fecha);
    tvdireccion.setText(direccion);
    tvtelefono.setText(telefono);
    tvlugar.setText(lugar);
    tvestado.setText(estado);
    txobservaciones.setText(observaciones);

    // decicion para comprobar el status inicial del radiobutton
    status = tvestado.getText().toString();
    if (status.equals("Activo")){
        activo.setChecked(true);
    }else if (status.equals("Pendiente")){
        pendiente.setChecked(true);
    }else if (status.equals("Concluido")){
        concluido.setChecked(true);
    }else if (status.equals("No Procede")){
        noprocede.setChecked(true);
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    borrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txobservaciones.setText("");
        }
    });
    actualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            String folio, estado, observaciones;

            folio = tvfolio.getText().toString();
            estado = tvestado.getText().toString();
            observaciones = txobservaciones.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    turnar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}

class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

        pdialog.dismiss();
        try {



            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private static String readURL(String theUrl) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // create a url object
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);
        // create a urlconnection object
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();
}
```

}

Este es mi codigo json

```
   <?php

  $estado = $_GET["estado"];
  $folio = $_GET["folio"];
  $observaciones = $_GET["observaciones"];

  $link =      mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx")  or die("Error en la conexion" . mysqli_error($link));

   $resultado = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE solicitudes 
                                SET folio = '$folio',                                                                           
                                    estado = '$status',
                                    observaciones = '$observaciones'                        
                                WHERE folio = '$folio' ORDER BY folio  DESC");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TE DEJARE UN EJEMPLO DE INICIO DE SESIÓN QUE YO MISMO HE ELABORADO.**
1ro. La clase que te permitirá enviar datos a un servidor web (cualquiera que sea). No recuerdo donde lo encontré pero lo adapté a mis necesidades.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class clsAndroidPHP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public static final int ESPERA_CONEXION=10000;
    public static final int ESPERA_LECTURA=15000;
    private Context ContextoClase;
    HttpURLConnection ConexionHTTP;
    URL DireccionURL = null;
    int nTotDatEnvio;
    public clsAndroidPHP(Context ContextoConst) {
        this.ContextoClase = ContextoConst;
    }
    private OnTaskExecutionFinished _task_finished_event;

    public interface OnTaskExecutionFinished    {
        public void OnTaskFihishedEvent(String Result);
    }

    public void setOnTaskFinishedEvent(OnTaskExecutionFinished _event)   {
        if(_event != null)    {
            this._task_finished_event = _event;
        }
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        nTotDatEnvio = arg0.length;
        /*Intentar crear URL de servidor*/
        try {
            DireccionURL = new URL(arg0[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR-URL";
        }
        /*Intentar establecer conexión y enviar datos al servidor web*/
        try {
            // Configurar conexión mediante HttpURLConnection
            ConexionHTTP = (HttpURLConnection)DireccionURL.openConnection();
            ConexionHTTP.setReadTimeout(ESPERA_LECTURA);
            ConexionHTTP.setConnectTimeout(ESPERA_CONEXION);
            ConexionHTTP.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // activar envio (setDoInput) y recepción (setDoOutput)
            ConexionHTTP.setDoInput(true);
            ConexionHTTP.setDoOutput(true);
            // Añadir parámetros a URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            for (int nDatEnvio=1; nDatEnvio<nTotDatEnvio;nDatEnvio++){
                builder.appendQueryParameter("DATO" + String.valueOf(nDatEnvio), arg0[nDatEnvio]);
            }
            String Peticion = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            // abrir conexion para enviar datos
            OutputStream Salida = ConexionHTTP.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter Escribir = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Salida, "UTF-8"));
            Escribir.write(Peticion);
            Escribir.flush();
            Escribir.close();
            Salida.close();
            ConexionHTTP.connect();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR-CON";
        }
        /*Intentar leer datos del servidor*/
        try {
            int Respuesta = ConexionHTTP.getResponseCode();
            // Si la conexión ha sido establecida correctamente
            if (Respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // Leer datos del servidor
                InputStream Entrada = ConexionHTTP.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader Leer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Entrada));
                StringBuilder Resultado = new StringBuilder();
                String Linea;
                while ((Linea = Leer.readLine()) != null) {
                    Resultado.append(Linea);
                }
                // Pasar datos al método onPostExecute
                return(Resultado.toString());
            }else{
                return ("ERROR-RESP");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR-RESP2";
        } finally {
            ConexionHTTP.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(this._task_finished_event != null)        {
            this._task_finished_event.OnTaskFihishedEvent(result);
        }  else     {
            //
        }

    }
}
```

2do: Como utilizarlo:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class fraSesion extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lytsesion, container, false);
        Button xSesion = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSesion);
        final EditText xUsu = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario);
        final EditText xClave = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtClave);

        xSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String sUsu, sClave, sURL;
                sUsu = xUsu.getText().toString();
                sClave = xClave.getText().toString();
                sURL = "http://www.sitio.com/sesion.php";
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //IMPLEMENTANDO LA CLASE PARA ENVIAR DATOS A UN SERVIDOR WEB
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //aqui uso getActivity() porque lo estoy llamando desde un fragment
                clsAndroidPHP cHTTP = new clsAndroidPHP(getActivity());
                //aqui envio la URL, el Usuario y su clave (contraseña)
                cHTTP.execute(sURL, sUsu, sClave);

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //CAPTURANDO RESULTADOS DEVUELTOS
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                /*evento que indica que Asyn Task a finalizado y devuelto los resultados*/
                cHTTP.setOnTaskFinishedEvent(new clsAndroidPHP.OnTaskExecutionFinished() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnTaskFihishedEvent(String result) {
                        String CadenaJSON = result;
                        if (CadenaJSON != null) {
                            if (CadenaJSON.equals("ERROR-URL") || CadenaJSON.equals("ERROR-CON") || CadenaJSON.equals("ERROR-RESP") || CadenaJSON.equals("ERROR-RESP2")) {
                                //Toast para mostrar un mensaje de error por conexión
                            }else {
                                try {
                                    /*aqui convierto el string JSON de PHP en objetos JSON para parsearlo
                                    y leer sus valores*/
                                    JSONObject ObjetoJSON = new JSONObject(CadenaJSON);
                                    String sMen1 = ObjetoJSON.getString("MEN1");
                                    String sMen2 = ObjetoJSON.getString("MEN2");
                                    /*aquí consulto el valor de cada item JSON*/
                                    if (sMen1.equals("ERROR")) {
                                        //toast si usuario no puede iniciar sesion
                                    }else if (sMen1.equals("CORRECTO")) {
                                        // codigo si el usuario si puede iniciar sesión, que puede 
                                        // llamar a un fragment o un activity
                                        // en la variable sMen2 se almacenará el nombre del usuario encontrado
                                        // el cual puedes enviarlo con bundle
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    //Toast indicacndo que JSON es erróneo
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            //Toast indicando que JSON no se puede leer
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
       return view;
    }
 }
```

> Los datos que se envían a la clase son a manera de array, por tanto el Primer parametro (pos 0) siempre debe ser la URL, a partir del segundo parámetro (pos >=1) puede ser cualquier cosa, pueden ser cuantos quieras.
>
> Como mínimo deberás mandar la URL y al menos un dato, sino tienes nada que mandar aparte de la URL, este puede ser un String Vacío, de lo contrario la clase de envío fallará porque no recibió un parametro despues de la URL. Ejm.

```
            cHTTP.execute(sURL, "");
```

3ro: La parte del PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['DATO1']) and isset($_POST['DATO2'])){
        $sUsuar = $_POST['DATO1'];
        $sClave = $_POST['DATO2'];

        /*consulta SQL para verificiar login y su respectiva 
        verificion bla bla bla*/

        /*si el login es correcto envio un JSON de CORRECTO y los datos del usuario en la base de datos*/
        echo "{'MEN1':'CORRECTO','MEN2':'$NOMBRE_USUARIO'}";
        /*si es incorrecto, envio un JSON de Error*/
        echo "{'MEN1':'ERROR','MEN2':'NADA'}";
    }
?>
```

Espero te sirva, es un ejemplo bien completo.